# << Plus on construit [de ? des ?] prisons, plus on les remplit >>

Tags: de, plus

<< Plus on construit **de** prisons, plus on les remplit >>

<< Plus on construit **des** prisons, plus on les remplit >>

Les deux expressions semblent courantes. Mais les deux sont-elles correctes ?

Comment: Tout dépend de qui juge... ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les deux sont grammaticalement correctes, avec des syntaxes différentes. Mais la phrase avec *de* est plus naturelle.

> Plus on construit **de** prisons, plus on les remplit.

= « Quand on construit **plus de prisons**, on les remplit plus. »

C'est la phrase idiomatique.

> Plus on construit **des** prisons, plus on les remplit.

= « Quand on passe plus de temps à construire des prisons, on les remplit plus. »

Dans cette interprétation, le comparatif porte non pas sur le nombre de prisons, mais sur l'action de construire des prisons. Si l'on passe plus de temps (ou d'effort ou autre quantité implicite) à construire des prisons, alors on les remplit plus. La phrase est correcte mais maladroite, en partie parce que le comparatif porte sur quelque chose d'implicite, et que cette chose implicite n'a pas un rapport évident avec la deuxième partie de la phrase.

Voici un exemple où *des* est plus naturel :

> Plus on construit **des** prisons, plus on acquiert de l'expérience.

= « Quand on passe plus de temps à construire des prisons, on acquiert de l'expérience. »

Si l'on [compare « plus [pronom] [verbe] de [nom] » avec « plus [pronom] [verbe] des [nom] »](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plus+_PRON_+_VERB_+de+_NOUN_%2C+plus+_PRON_+_VERB_+des+_NOUN_&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3), on voit que *de* est plus fréquent mais pas ultradominant.

[image: plus PRON VERB de NOUN,plus PRON VERB des NOUN]

---

En règle générale, je pense que beaucoup de locuteurs natifs ne font pas vraiment attention et utiliseraient à peu près indifféremment *de* ou *des* dans beaucoup de cas.

Voici un autre exemple trouvé au hasard d'Internet.

> Plus on voit des œuvres d'art, plus on est prêt à en recevoir ! ([source](https://www.museumtv.art/artnews/articles/je-decouvre-lart-moderne-de-guillaume-bottazzi-un-livre-ludique/))

Il y a une légère nuance entre « plus on voit des œuvres d'art » (plus on passe de temps à regarder des œuvres d'art) et « plus on voit d'œuvres d'art » (plus on voit d'œuvres différentes, indépendamment du temps passé sur chaque). Ici je pense que le locuteur voulait plutôt dire « plus on voit d'œuvres »...

Et voici un autre exemple où *des* est clairement le bon choix :

> Plus on s'avance vers le vote, plus on voit des interrogations monter dans chaque famille politique. (source : [un homme politique via *Le Figaro*](https://www.lefigaro.fr/actualite-france/2013/11/29/01016-20131129ARTFIG00282-prostitution-les-deputes-hesitants.php))

Les interrogations ne sont pas vraiment quantifiables individuellement : c'est leur volume qui compte, donc le comparatif porte sur le groupe verbal « voir des interrogations monter … ».

Encore un exemple, que je trouve plus tranché : le proverbe

> Plus on est de fous, plus on rit.

Ici *de* est obligatoire, à la fois parce que c'est un proverbe (donc figé) et parce que *des* n'aurait pas du tout le bon sens. « <sup>?</sup>Plus on est des fous, plus on rit » signifierait plus les personnes concernées sont folles, avec un comparatif portant sur le niveau de folie et non sur le nombre de personnes. À noter qu'il s'agit de l'utilisation moderne de *on* comme une première personne du pluriel : « plus nous sommes fous, plus nous rions ».

Answer (score 1):

La forme idiomatique est *Plus on construit **de** prisons, plus on les remplit*. En effet, la forme *directe* serait *on construit plus de prisons*, et dans ce contexte, *plus de* est synonyme de *davantage de* et signifie qu'on rajoute de nouvelles prisons.

Comment: En anglais il y a une différence subtile entre *The more prisons one builds* and *The more one builds prisons*. Pour la première, il s’agit sans aucune ambiguité du nombre de prisons. La deuxième permet à la fois cette même interprétation et celle qui concerne la quantité d’effort exercé en construction de n’importe combien de prisons. Y-a-t’il une distinction semblable en français?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum [Oui, ça serait la distinction de/des, justement](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/53890).

Answer (score 1):

Il y a trois questions : les deux expressions sont elles correctes, les deux ont-elles le même sens, et laquelle exprime ce qu’on imagine qu’elle exprime.

Dans << Plus on construit des prisons >>, ˋplusˋ se rapporte à construire.
Ce qui dans ce cas précis, stricto sensu, ne veut pas dire grand chose, construire n’étant pas associé à une notion de quantité (On construit ou on ne construit pas)

Comme l’indique une réponse, cela pourrait cependant être interprété comme une ellipse de << Plus de temps on passe à construire >>, ou << Plus souvent on construit >> c’est correct mais cela introduit un flou

Dans << Plus on construit de prisons >> ˋplusˋ se rapporte à prisons, parce que prisons est dénombrable. Mais si on avait << Plus on parle de moi >> plus se rapporterait à parler.

Des deux options, << Plus on construit de prisons >> est donc la seule forme acceptable pour dire que si l’on construit plus de prisons, on les remplira.